# Which time zone will be used; SharePoint site regional setting time zone OR the Azure web app time zone

Tags: sharepoint, timezone, azure-web-app-service

I have developed a remote event receiver for our SharePoint online site, the remote event receiver is hosted inside azure web app. Now inside the remote event receiver i am getting the value of a DateTime field, as follow:-

```
DateTime approveDate = (DateTime)projectItem["ApproveDate"];
```

**so i am not sure which time zone will be used to render the DateTiem**; the SharePoint regional setting's time zone which is:-
[image]

OR the azure web app Location's time zone:-
[image]

now if inside my remote event receiver code, i wrote this code `System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName` i will get `Coordinated Universal Time`.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Don't use the `System.TimeZone` class.  It has been replaced with `System.TimeZoneInfo`.  The current time zone is `System.TimeZoneInfo.Local`
- The *location* of the Azure web app refers to which Azure region is hosting it.  It has no bearing on time zone whatsoever.
- The default time zone in Azure is UTC (Coordinated Universal Time).  In most cases, you should not change it.  Instead you should handle time zone conversions in your application code using the methods on the `TimeZoneInfo` class.
- If you *must* change the server's time zone, Azure App Service allows for a configuration value in the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` field.  [See these docs for details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management#how-do-i-set-the-server-time-zone-for-my-web-app)  *This should be used only as a last resort if you absolutely cannot modify the code.*
- In the code you showed, the time zone has no relevance.  You are simply copying a `DateTime` value from one place to another.  It really depends on how you got the value into your `projectItem` dictionary to begin with.  It also depends on what value was *sent* to your code.  You should do some debugging to see what you actually are getting.  Be sure to check the `Kind` property as well as the date and time.
- In the SharePoint screenshot you showed, I believe the time zone is used within SharePoint only.  You'll have to experiment to see if it affects the values sent to your code.  However, the regional locale will absolutely not affect the time zone.  Locale and time zone are orthoganal concepts.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful reply. so could the scenario be as follow, since inside my SharePoint's regional setting i am using the GMT+4 time zone and the azure uses the UTC, then inside my code when the `projectItem["ApproveDate"]` equals let say `30/09/2020 00:00:00` it will be shown inside my code as `29/09/2020 20:00:00`?

Comment: That depends on a lot.  Try it and see what you get.  If indeed that's what you get, you can convert using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` and similar methods.

Comment: you mean to convert the DateTime from GMT+4 to UTC?